# DBMS ERD Design

Tags: php, sql, database, erd

I am planning out an application's database. I have an employee table. I want to store every employee's education degree. Adding an education column to the employee table itself will cause redundancies.

I'm unsure if adding an education table is the best way to go about it as every employee could have multiple degrees.

I was wondering what would be the best way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

It probably makes sense to have a separate education table to keep track of degrees since, like you said, employees can have multiple degrees.

Just add the employee id (or whatever the primary key is) as a foreign key on the education table.